# Case sensitive no method do form?

Tags: html

Eu sempre uso `method="post"` (minusculo), mas pesquisando tutoriais na internet, maioria usa `method="POST"` (maiúsculo), tem alguma diferença isso? pode causar problemas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [especificação do HTML4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-method) diz:

> Possible (**case-insensitive**) values are "get" (the default) and "post"

ou seja **não faz diferênça ter letra grande ou pequena**. Lendo a [especificação do HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-method) não refere nada sobre o assunto, por isso mantem-se. De qualquer maneira uma vêz referido tão claro numa das especificações seria muito dificil mudar no futuro.

Answer (score 2):

### Não.

Atributos não são case-sensitive.